# .pdf in tabs default zoom

Tags: html, css, pdf

i got a question about the default zoom in .pdfs. I created a pdf to explain how to activate a product key, its actually in german but you can get the point of my problem better if you see it:

http://evoxity.net/pdfguides/battle.net/deutsch/battle.netde.pdf

by default the pictures are not sharp, if i zoom 2 times out its in the same zoom as it is on photoshop with "100%". The only way i know is, to create a pixture with a higher width to scale it down by itself but that need a lot of trying untill i gound the width i need so i want to ask if there is something like creating a .html and do something like  or something like that.

Comment: I found this manual: http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf

and tryed http://evoxity.net/pdfguides/battle.net/deutsch/battle.netde.pdf?#zoom=75 but the zoom wont change.